# Javascript calling other function without reason

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach an event to a button and if user clicks, an alert should appear. But here, even if the user doesnt click, the alert appears.

Js File :

```
var init = function (m) {
        _m = m;
        var actionButton = document.getElementById("action");
        if (actionButton) {
            var buttonId = "action";
             if (actionButton.attachEvent) {                
                actionButton.attachEvent("onclick", _onActionClick(buttonId));
            }
        }

var _onActionClick = function (buttonId) {
        alert("3");
}
```

Here, I get alert 3.

But, with this code, I do not get alert 3.

```
var init = function (m) {
        _m = m;
        var actionButton = document.getElementById("action");
        if (actionButton) {
            var buttonId = "action";
             if (actionButton.attachEvent) {                
                actionButton.attachEvent("onclick", _onActionClick);
            }
        }

var _onActionClick = function (){
        alert("3");
}
```

Can someone, let me know where am I going wrong ?

Comment: If your browser doesn't support .`attachEvent`, perhaps falling back to standard `.addEventListener` might give you better success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onclick` needs a function. You're using the return value of `_onActionClick(buttonId)` which is `undefined`

```
// no good!
actionButton.attachEvent("onclick", _onActionClick(buttonId));
```

Try using an actual function

```
actionButton.attachEvent("onclick", function(event) {
  _onActionClick(buttonId)
})
```

---

Or you can define `_onActionClick` in curried form

```
var _onActionClick = function(buttonId) {
  return function(event) {
    console.log(buttonId, event)
  }
}

// now when you call _onActionClick(buttonId) it will return a function ...
actionButton.attachEvent("onclick", _onActionClick("action"))
```